# How to create a custom example module?

Tags: 9

I want to create a custom module *in minimum*, i.e. a module which can be installed but generally doesn't do anything just for the sake of understanding how are custom modules get created after some hard time with the documentation.

**example.info.yml**

```
name: example
type: module
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
description: 'example'
```

**example.php**

```
<?php
?>
```

Assuming that this is the way to go and nothing essential is missing, how is the connection between the two files is done (shouldn't I notify example.info.yml about example.php)?

Comment: Minimum is just an info file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**How the files are connected**

Drupal will automatically execute the PHP file with the module name **and the extension .module**; this is a special case.

So, you need to rename **example.php** to **example.module**.

If you want to add additional PHP files that are not classes, you will need to include them.

For example, if I add a file **example.mail.php**, and I want to include that, I need to include it in **example.module** like this:

`include_once 'example.mail.inc';`

But I do not need to include **example.module** because it is a special case.  **example.module** will always be executed if it exists.

**Verifying example.module is included**

You can use the [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) with kint to debug Drupal, and this is a relatively easy way to check if a file is being included.

If you enable the Devel module, add the following code to **example.php**, and then [rebuild the cache](https://drupalize.me/tutorial/clear-drupals-cache?p=2512), Drupal will use kint to print the form ID on every page that includes a form.

```
function example_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  kint($form_id);
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't really do includes or require statements, they'd be classes/services callable or injectable anywhere within Drupal. The filename for hooks should also end in .module.

Comment: @Kevin Whoops, good point about the filename.  I personally use includes to keep various types of hooks separate; I added a note to make that more clear.

Comment: In Drupal 8/9 PHP files are in the src/ directory where they are discovered by the [autoloader](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/psr-4-namespaces-and-autoloading-in-drupal-8). There are some specific PHP files which Drupal includes bypassing the autoloader like this .module file.